# How to clear a specific NuGet package from local cache using command line?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

**Question**

Is it possible to clear a specific NuGet package from NuGet local cache using command line?

**Context**

I would like to ensure when I am executing a package restore operation for a project, the very latest server binaries will be restored, not something from the cache. At the same time I do not want to delete all packages from the cache.

Answer (score 18):

If you have NuGet.exe version 3.3 or higher you can clear the entire cache from the command line:

```
nuget locals <all | http-cache | packages-cache | global-packages> -clear
```

If your NuGet packages are downloaded to the NuGet v2 cache then you could just have a simple script to delete a particular .nupkg file from the packages cache.

```
del %LocalAppData%\NuGet\Cache\NUnit.2.6.4.nupkg
```

With the NuGet v3 cache the structure is a bit different so you would need to do remove a set of directories:

```
rmdir %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\NUnit\2.6.4 /s
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can't currently delete a specific package from the cache using the `nuget` or `dotnet` cli. There is a github issue to address that: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5713
- As [Matt Ward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37213181/10871073) states, you are left with having to use filesystem commands to delete a package from the cache. With nuget V3+, on mac/linux, the command is:

```
rm -rf ~/.nuget/packages/<package-name>
```

- When I was trying to delete a specific package from the cache, what I really wanted was to do so before I re-published that package to a local nuget repository (I use a fixed version number for the local repository to make [local development of nuget packages easier](https://www.nyckel.com/blog/local-development-and-testing-of-nuget-packages/)). I accomplished this by adding the following to the .csproj file of the nuget-packaged library:

```
    <Project>
      <Target Name="DeleteLocalCache" BeforeTargets="Pack">
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(NugetPackageRoot)/$(PackageId.ToLower())/1.0.0-local"/>
      </Target>
    </Project>
```